# Client Side File manipulation in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, silverlight, file-handling

I am an ASP.NET Developer. I want to develop a web app which will convert all the files with particular extensions from one format to another(eg : .txt to .docx or .docx to .txt) on the client machine. I can't see anything in ASP.NET that can do these things on the client machine. I was going through other SOPs and googling which was suggesting to use Silverlight, WPF, ActiveX scripts etc.

Please provide your suggestions. Thanks,

Comment: When you say one extenson to another in involves huge list of possibilities, this would get complicated to handle on clientside as the list grows. Best way to handle this is to convert on server side event or ajax call with or file url in response.

Comment: @VinayPandey: I will take care of those possibilities, and uploading file to the server is not feasible for me. Actually, the scenario is that user will select the folder and all the files in that folder will be converted to the desired extension.

Comment: If _"uploading to the server is not feasible"_, are then saying you need a client-side solution (some other application _running on the client_ - probably why you got those suggestions)? The "server side app" (ASP.net or otherwise) cannot "access client file system/files/folders" inherently (security).

Comment: @EdSF : You are right that we cannot access client file system, but what would be the another way to achieve this being a web based app only.. Will Silverlight serve the purpose?